# Open ID connect to authenticate with Azure AD AADSTS90019 error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, asp.net-core-2.0, adfs

I have setup my asp.net core 2.0 to authenticate against my Azure AD using openid connect. While this works fine for most users in my company, however there are certain users whom we call "external users", are unable to complete the sign process. The login will fail with AADSTS90019: The SAML 1.1 Assertion contains no ImmutableID of the user message.

What i know is that these users are only available in on-prem ad, and not synced to Azure AD. Is there anyway to overcome this? Is it a must to have the user in Azure AD for sign in to complete? As my understanding is that the authentication started by a call to Azure AD, then redirected to on-prem STS and STS would be able to authenticate as it has the user information and credentials...

Thanks.

Comment: Additional info:
My organization has the Azure AD setup with federation sign in (with password hash sync all turned off). The idea is that the authentication will be redirected to on prem ADFS to validate credentials.

I would like to know if this authentication flow would work if the user object is not synced to Azure AD? Is there a way to make this flow work, as I have special users object that are not synced to Azure AD, and they are the ones that unable to complete the sign in process with the error mentioned above

Comment: I'm pretty sure they need to be in AAD for them to be able to log in.

Comment: @juunas looks like my worst fear is confirmed. Is there anyway to overcome this and allow these users to complete the sign in?

Comment: From a purely technical standpoint, you cannot ask Azure AD to tell you a user's identity when AAD does not know the user even exists. Either a) sync the users or b) setup the login from your app to happen against ADFS instead of AAD.

Comment: Thanks @juunas looks like i need to pull some strings